# Flex 3: dynamically created checkbox column in datagrid - data population issues and event listener

Tags: apache-flex

I have a datagrid control in my mxml file:

Now in my AS file, in the result function when obtaining data from DB, I can create columns dynamically. Let's say I create 1 column (client name):

```
private function GetDebtors_Result(event:ResultEvent):void
{
var arrayCol:Array = new Array();
var xmlSrc:XML = new XML("<main></main>");
var xmlTmp:XML;
var colClientname:DataGridColumn;

//Build an XML from DB data received (could as well use "event.result" directly to act as dataprovider for the datagrid, but I needed to break it down here)
for each(var o:Object in event.result)
{
xmlTmp = <row>
<CLIENTNAME>{o.CLIENTNAME}</CLIENTNAME>
</row>;
xmlSrc.appendChild(xmlTmp);
}

//Create the column CLIENTNAME
colClientname = new DataGridColumn("CLIENTNAME");
colClientname.headerText = "Client Name";

//Add the newly created column in the "Column" array.
arrayCol.push(colClientname);

//Use the "Column" array to set the columns of the datagrid.  
dgSearch.columns = arrayCol;

//Populate the datagrid with the XML data.
dgSearch.dataProvider = xmlSrc.row;
}
```

This works well.

Now comes the issue: I need to add a second column which will contain checkboxes. They will be selected or deselected depending on the data from database. I'll show how I've done it by updating the same "GetDebtors_Result" function as above (added lines are commented as "// **ADDED**"):

```
private function GetDebtors_Result(event:ResultEvent):void
{
var arrayCol:Array = new Array();
var xmlSrc:XML = new XML("<main></main>");
var xmlTmp:XML;
var colClientname:DataGridColumn;
var colSel:DataGridColumn; // **ADDED**

//Build an XML from DB data received (could as well use "event.result" directly to act as dataprovider for the datagrid, but I needed to break it down here)
for each(var o:Object in event.result)
{
xmlTmp = <row>
<CLIENTNAME>{o.CLIENTNAME}</CLIENTNAME>
<SELECTED>{(o.SELECTED == 1)?true:false}</SELECTED>  //**ADDED**
</row>;
xmlSrc.appendChild(xmlTmp);
}

//Create the column CLIENTNAME
colClientname = new DataGridColumn("CLIENTNAME");
colClientname.headerText = "Client Name";

//Create the column SELECTED
colSel = new DataGridColumn("SELECTED"); // **ADDED**
colSel.headerText = ""; // **ADDED**
colSel.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(mx.controls.CheckBox); // **ADDED**
colSel.dataField = "SELECTED"; // **ADDED**

//Add the newly created column in the "Column" array.
arrayCol.push(colClientname);

//Add the "selection" column in the "Column" array.
arrayCol.push(colSel); // **ADDED**

//Use the "Column" array to set the columns of the datagrid.  
dgSearch.columns = arrayCol;

//Populate the datagrid with the XML data.
dgSearch.dataProvider = xmlSrc.row;
```

}

Problem #1: The checkbox column appears, I can check and uncheck the checkboxes, but they are not checked/unchecked respective to DB data when loaded.

Problem #2: How do I associate a function to the checkboxes, for instance one which will update the XML so that I can save the new data to the DB?

Anybody got the solution? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to describe all your columns in the DataGrid definition section in MXML? I would do so and then I would define some ItemRenderers to properly show your database content. Are the results always different and you have to build the DataGrid every time from scratch? If I have not understood your problem, explain it please in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a very old question that I saw today.
Hopefully you would have found out the solution by now, just in-case if anyone has same problem:

While adding a checkbox to column- just instantiate it 1st:

```
var chkTempCheck: Checkbox = new CheckBox();
```

Then set all the properties required:

```
chkTempCheck.selected = o.dBColumnToDecideCheckUnCheck
```

here 'o' is the Object you are using from event.result.
This will work for sure!

Answer (score 0):

The initial scenario was: all columns were defined in the mxml file. The checkbox column used itemrenderer and was working properly. I was using the same datagrid in 3 different cases - only thing was that some columns were set visible/invisible depending on the 'views'. The problem was when shifting 'views' and populate the grid and shift 'views' again, the column widths kept increasing exponentially. I excluded the checkbox column and everything worked fine; columns widths were ok. I included the checkbox column back and tried setting the column widths in AS file and the column-increasing-exponentially problem was fixed but the column widths were never the same when populating grid in view A and when populating grid in view B. ...So I ventured out in trying to set the columns in AS file just after obtaining DB data. Hope you can find yourself in those situations. Thanks for helping.